# Pywebkitgtk Three.js unable to detect WebGL

Tags: python, webkit, webgl, three.js

Background:

- OS: Fedora 16
- GPU: nVidia Corporation GF106 [GeForce GT 555M SDDR3] (rev a1)
- Python: 2.7.2
- pywebkit-gtk: pywebkitgtk.x86_64:1.1.8-1.fc16, webkitgtk-devel.x86_64 0:1.6.1-1.fc16

Python uses pywebkitgtk to generate a basic web browser, the following setting are set to True during this process.

```
setting = webkit.WebView.get_settings();

settings.set_property("enable-scripts", True)
settings.set_property("enable-webgl", True)
settings.set_property("enable-universal-access-from-file-uris", True)
settings.set_property("enable-developer-extras", True)
```

Issue:

The browser spawn without error. The following JS is loaded into the browser:

```
if( Detector.webgl ){                                                                                                               
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({                                                                                                                  
        antialias: true,             // to get smoother output                                                                                                 
        preserveDrawingBuffer: true  // to allow screenshot                                                                                            
    });      
    renderer.setClearColorHex( 0xBBBBBB, 1 );                                                                                                                                             
} else {                                                                                                                
    Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();                      
    return true;                                                                                                                  
}
```

Detector.webgl is **false**

If I run the index.html, which includes the above JS code, in Chrome Detector.webgl is **True**.

It seems to be a pywebkitgtk issue, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Please check if the webkitgtk package you're using is built with WebGL enabled (most likely not). The run-time setting doesn't mean it will turn on automatically.